How to disable an HTML submit button after it has been pressed?
I'm working on a signup page in PHP and JavaScript. When the user presses the "submit" button, the page starts to load before redirecting. If the user presses "submit" again, the page throws an error because the data has already been entered into the database the first time.
Here's a video of the problem.
I want to disable the "submit" button for 15 seconds after the first click, as long as the form information is valid. I'm using PHP and JavaScript for this.
I tried the following code, but it didn't work and didn't change a thing:
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (<?php echo (($vemail !== null) && ($vfullname !== null) && ($vusername !== null) && ($vpassword     !== null) && ($vbirthdate !== null) && ($vgender !== null)); ?>) {
    submitButton.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      submitButton.disabled = false;
    }, 15000); // 15 seconds
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

The conditions for the form to be considered valid are:
(($vemail !== null) && ($vfullname !== null) && ($vusername !== null) && ($vpassword !== null) &&     ($vbirthdate !== null) && ($vgender !== null));

The submit button is:
<form method="post"> <button id="submit-button" name="submit-button" type="submit">Sign Up!</button> </form>


There are two main problems with your code:

PHP generates a page, sends it to the client, and then it's done. The PHP code doesn't run again until the page is re-loaded. If you want client-side input validation based on the current contents of the form, you have to do it fully in JavaScript, not with a JavaScript / PHP combo. (If you want this if statement to be based on a fixed value, known at page load time, your combo approach can be used.)
You might prefer to use the browser's built-in form validation functionality to achieve this specific functionality.

event.preventDefault(); prevents the default behaviour of the button – that is, submitting the form. You want the form submitted the first time the button is pressed!


However, there are problems with your approach, too:

Disabling the form's submit button does not prevent the form from being submitted. Hitting Enter on an input box will also submit the form, as will some assistive technology.
Refreshing the target page will also re-submit the form. There's no way to prevent this, though returning an HTTP 303 See Other from the form target is good practice that goes some way towards ameliorating this issue.

A better approach would be using an idempotent method like PUT. Unfortunately, PUT isn't supported in HTML forms: you have to use POST. Fortunately, there's no reason you can't implement PUT semantics in the server-side code that handles this response.

If the user presses "submit" again, the page throws an error because the data has already been entered into the database the first time.

Make this page not throw an error, if the data being entered is identical. (Or, go further, and only ever show out-of-band errors, to prevent user enumeration attacks from leaking data.)

The issue isn't that the button can be clicked twice, the issue is that you are trying to validate the form on the event of the button click. Like you discovered yourself, this is not a good idea.
You can find a lot of example on how to validate a form on the submit event. That works, however, it is better to use the build-in form validation. If you use the required attribute on the required form fields, the form will only submit (and only ONCE) if all the fields are valid. As a starting point, a form field is valid when the required form field have a value. If you would like to be more specific, like setting a minimum length of a password etc., you can use the attributes minlength, maxlength and pattern for text input.


<form method="post">
  <label>User name: <input type="text" name="username" required></label>
  <label>Password: <input type="password" name="password" required></label>
  <button type="submit">Sign Up!</button>
</form>



